# How to pass swift String to c function in Swift 5

Tags: string, function, type-conversion, swift5

I want to pass swift String to c function in swift 5 .

String in swift

```
var key = "zxcvbnmqwertyui"
var error = "noerror"
```

C function declaration

```
extern KeyRef key(char* p0, char** p1);
```

C Function declaration in swift

```
public func key(_ p0: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>!, _ p1: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>!) -> KeyRef
```

Question :
How can i pass swift string (i.e key and error) to c function (i.e key ) ?

Answer (score 0):

***How can i pass swift string (i.e key and error) to c function (i.e key ) ?***

The answer depends on how the function treats its parameters.

- 1. Does it modify the contents passed by its parameters?
- 2. Does it require pre-allocated region for the address passed by `p1`?

I assume,

- 1. NO for `p0`, YES for `p1`.
- 2. NO

In that case you should better update the function header as:

```
extern KeyRef key(const char* p0, char** p1);
```

Which is imported into Swift as:

```
public func key(_ p0: UnsafePointer<Int8>!, _ p1: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>!) -> KeyRef!
```

You can call it as follows:

```
let p0 = "zxcvbnmqwertyui"
var error: String? = nil
var errorPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>? = nil

let keyRef = key(p0, &errorPtr)
if let errorMsg = errorPtr {
    error = String(cString: errorMsg)
}
```

---

If you cannot touch the C-function header and use it as is:

```
extern KeyRef key(char* p0, char** p1);
```

Then you may need a little more:

```
let p0 = "zxcvbnmqwertyui"
var p0CStr = Array(p0.utf8CString)
var error: String? = nil
var errorPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>? = nil

let keyRef = key(&p0CStr, &errorPtr)
if let errorMsg = errorPtr {
    error = String(cString: errorMsg)
}
```

---

If my assumptions does not match the requirement of your C-function, the code above would not work and you might need to show the precise spec of it.

Comment: thanks for replying ,  Only p1 value will get modified . p0 will for reading purpose only its value will not get modified .